# CSS how to center horizontal menus?

Tags: html, css, web, alignment, center

i have this problem
i cant center this simple CSS Horizontam menu
can u help me how to do this?
so here is my CSS code

```
<style>
{
float:left;
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
}
a
{
float:left;
width:6em;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
background-color:purple;
padding:0.2em 0.6em;
border-right:1px solid white;
border-left:1px solid white;
}
a:hover {background-color:#ff3300;}
li {display:inline;}
</style>
```

here is my html

```
</head>
<body bgcolor="gray">
<font face="calibri">

<center><img style="float:center" src="header.jpg" alt="" ></center>
<center>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</center>

</ul>
```

thank you for helping me
im just a new member here.
pls reply thanks

Comment: First step is to remove `<center>`. There is also no `float: center` css attribute. You also seem to be missing something in your css. the first `{...}` block has no selectors specified...

Comment: yep i tried to edit everything and change it to center. just trying something. sorry bout that

Comment: Generally, you center by setting the left and right margins to `auto`.

Comment: you also might want to assign a rule to the first block of CSS lol

Comment: `<center><ul> </center></ul>` is not a valid HTML ... it should be `<center><ul></ul></center>` ... properly nested

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtL8L/1/)

Use `text-align: center` and remove all `float: left` on `ul` and `a` tags.

```
ul {    
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: @user3236746 You only asked to center those horizontal menu and it's now centered :)